# Is there something in between Traversable and MonoTraversable?

Tags: haskell, types, traversal, typeclass, parametric-polymorphism

I have a datatype and accompanying function that looks very much like some sort of traversal. Here’s a simplified example:

```
data Foo x = MkFoo (Bar x) (Bar x)

almostTraverse :: Applicative f => (Bar a -> f (Bar b)) -> Foo a -> f (Foo b)
almostTraverse f (MkFoo x y) = MkFoo <$> f x <*> f y
```

Assume that `Bar` is some opaque type, and isn’t necessarily a functor. Is there some typeclass that’s a generalization of `almostTraverse`? It’s not `otraverse` from `MonoTraversable`, because the result type inside the applicative doesn’t have to be exactly the same as the input type, and it’s not `traverse` from `Traversable` either, because the function passed in needs to be aware of the `Bar` despite it not being in the type parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lens package would call this a [`Traversal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#t:Traversal):

```
almostTraverse :: Traversal (Foo a) (Foo b) (Bar a) (Bar b)
```

You could consider making an instance of the [`Each`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Each.html#t:Each) typeclass, as in

```
instance Each (Foo a) (Foo b) (Bar a) (Bar b) where
    each f (MkFoo x y) = liftA2 MkFoo (f x) (f y)
```

Comment: I redirected the links so they don't just go into the enormous pile of `Control.Lens.Combinators`. Hope that's okay.